# Need to Copy Dynamic Span content into Input field for Form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, input, datepicker, html

i'm new here & i'm a noob with javascript, so please, be gentle & detailed :-)

i snagged this script ([link](http://www.tikalk.com/incubator/week-picker-using-jquery-ui-datepicker)) to allow users to select a whole week from a calendar. it works perfectly as-is, as it should.

my problem is, it puts the selected week results as inline content in a SPAN tag. 
i really need the results to be put into a FORM Hidden INPUT value so it can be submitted with the form it'll be in... automatically.

i have researched & researched for 2 whole days; read as much as i could about jquery, etc. but i'm just not "getting it".

would really appreciate some help.
THANKS!!!

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var startDate;
var endDate;

var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
    }, 1);
}

$('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
        var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
        $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings     ));

        selectCurrentWeek();
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var cssClass = '';
        if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
            cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
        return [true, cssClass];
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        selectCurrentWeek();
    }
});

$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="week-picker"></div>
<p><label>Week :</label> 
<span id="startDate"></span> - <span id="endDate"></span>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. (or here on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qr7g/) )

Just change the type to hidden, I only set it to text so you can easily see it's working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
            $('#endDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="week-picker"></div>
    <br /><br />
    <form action="/somewhere">
    <label>Week :</label> <input type="text" id="startDate"></input> - <input type="text" id="endDate"></input>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

​
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU !!!! you Rock man! i REALLY appreciate this tweak. helps me out tremendously! if there's anything i can do for you graphically (which is my stronger suit), please don't hesitate to ask. peace:jason.